# check if a number already exist in a list in python

Tags: python, list, data-structures, set, append

I am writing a python program where I will be appending numbers into a list, but I don't want the numbers in the list to repeat. So how do I check if a number is already in the list before I do `list.append()`?

Comment: Why not just use a `set`?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You could do

```
if item not in mylist:
     mylist.append(item)
```

But you should really use a set, like this :

```
myset = set()
myset.add(item)
```

**EDIT:** If order is important but your list is very big, you should probably use both a list *and* a set, like so:

```
mylist = []
myset = set()
for item in ...:
    if item not in myset:
        mylist.append(item)
        myset.add(item)
```

This way, you get fast lookup for element existence, but you keep your ordering. If you use the naive solution, you will get O(n) performance for the lookup, and that can be bad if your list is big

Or, as @larsman pointed out, you can use OrderedDict to the same effect:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

mydict = OrderedDict()
for item in ...:
    mydict[item] = True
```

Comment: There is no such method as `append` for `set`. You surely meant `add`.

Comment: Again, sets are *orderless*, so it's not equivalent.

Comment: In Python >=2.7, an `OrderedDict` with `True` as the value would work, too.

Comment: @larsmans That's right, i actually prefer the set solution, because using dicts with True as values remind me of javascript, but adding it to the answer anyway :)

Comment: I see your point, but the main benefit of `OrderedDict` is that you only have one container object to worry about without having to define a new class.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to have unique elements in your list, then why not use a set, if of course, order does not matter for you: -

```
>>> s = set()
>>> s.add(2)
>>> s.add(4)
>>> s.add(5)
>>> s.add(2)
>>> s
39: set([2, 4, 5])
```

If order is a matter of concern, then you can use: -

```
>>> def addUnique(l, num):
...     if num not in l:
...         l.append(num)
...     
...     return l
```

You can also find an [`OrderedSet`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) recipe, which is referred to in [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)

Comment: so if I want the numbers to be ascending order, I have to do that? could you explain that part a bit more? (yes I do have to have a ordered set)

Comment: @Jenny.. It's doing nothing, but just checking whether an element `num`, is already in the list `l` or not, by using `not in` operator, and if it's not already there, it is adding it to the list, and then finally returning the list.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your numbers in ascending order you can add them into a set and then sort the set into an ascending list.

```
s = set()
if number1 not in s:
  s.add(number1)
if number2 not in s:
  s.add(number2)
...
s = sorted(s)  #Now a list in ascending order
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a set object instead. Just `add` numbers to the set. They inherently do not replicate.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a number is in a list one can use the `in` keyword.

Let's create a list

```
exampleList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now let's see if it contains the number 4:

```
contains = 4 in exampleList

print(contains)
>>>> True
```

As you want to append when an element is not in a list, the `not in` can also help

```
exampleList2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

notcontain = "e" not in exampleList2

print(notcontain)
>>> False
```

But, as others have mentioned, you may want to consider using a different data structure, more specifically, [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). See examples below ([Source](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)):

```
basket = {'apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'banana'}
>>> print(basket)                      # show that duplicates have been removed
{'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'apple'}

'orange' in basket                 # fast membership testing
True

'crabgrass' in basket
False

# Demonstrate set operations on unique letters from two words
...
a = set('abracadabra')
b = set('alacazam')
a                                  # unique letters in a
>>> {'a', 'r', 'b', 'c', 'd'}

a - b                              # letters in a but not in b
>>> {'r', 'd', 'b'}

a | b                              # letters in a or b or both
>>> {'a', 'c', 'r', 'd', 'b', 'm', 'z', 'l'}

a & b                              # letters in both a and b
>>> {'a', 'c'}

a ^ b                              # letters in a or b but not both
>>> {'r', 'd', 'b', 'm', 'z', 'l'}
```