# How can I search through a list in python for something that might not exist?

Tags: python

For example something like:

```
if l.index(a)== -1:
    l += [a]
```

If I run something like this, I will get a value error.I am assuming this is not a new problem.

Comment: Please avoid using names like list, dict etc as they shadow the in-built functions

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if a number already exist in a list in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667578/check-if-a-number-already-exist-in-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Your question is vague. Tell us exactly what error you see, and provide code that reproduces the error (not code "something like" what causes the problem).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to check if a value exist in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exist-in-a-list)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not just use:

```
if a not in some_list:
    some_list.append(a)
```