# check if a string is in a list, and if not append it to that list

Tags: python, list, append

I have written the following code using Python 2.7 to search the list 'dem_nums' for the first three characters from each element in the list 'dems', and if they are not present to append them. When I run the code the list 'dem_nums' is returned as empty. I've tried using this article to help ([check if a number already exist in a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667578/check-if-a-number-already-exist-in-a-list-in-python)) but using the information there hasn't solved the problem.

```
dems = ["083c15", "083c16", "083f01", "083f02"]
dem_nums = []
    for dem in dems:
         dem_num = dem[0:3]
         if dem_num not in dem_nums:
              dem_nums.append(dem_num)
```

Comment: your code is working so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with your code ,but as a more elegant way you can just use a generator in `set` function :

```
>>> set(i[:3] for i in dems)
set(['083'])
```

As 'set' object does not support indexing for access to elements you can convert it to list !

```
my_list=list(set(i[:3] for i in dems))
```

your code :

```
>>> dem_nums = []
>>> for dem in dems:
...          dem_num = dem[0:3]
...          if dem_num not in dem_nums:
...               dem_nums.append(dem_num)
... 
>>> dem_nums
['083']
```

Comment: if I use the set function am I able to call information from it? For example, if the set contained '083' and '084' could I call each string individually?

Comment: @David No 'set' object does not support indexing , you can convert it to list !see the edit!

Answer (score 0):

```
dems = ["083c15", "083c16", "083f01", "083f02","084f56"]
dem_nums = []
for dem in dems:
         dem_num_ = dem[0:3]
         if dem_num_ not in dem_nums:
              dem_nums.append(dem_num_)

print dem_nums
```

Its working fine on my machine , and the output is :

> ['083', '084']

for the given dems